# Ignore duplicate key insertion through configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a system which calls an API many times a day that returns a JSON array. The objects in the JSON array are made up of three levels which are the wrapper, details, and items. For example:

```
[
   {
      "Key": "value",
      "Details": [
           {
               "Key": "Value",
                "Item": {
                     "Id": 1,
                      "Title": "abc" 
                 }
           }
       ]

   }
]
```

My database model also adopts this structure meaning that I have a master table, a details table, and an item table. To be specific, the details table has two relations, one is to the master table and one is to the items table.

My client context has been designed in a general way which means that it is not aware of what it is catching, de-serialzing, and saving.

```
 ISerializer serializer; 
 DbContext db;
 String url;
 public ClientContext(ISerializer serializer, DbContext db, String url){
      this.serializer = serializer;
      this.db = db;
      this.url = url;
 }
 public async Task RequestAsync() {
    ... 
    return response; 
 }
 public async Task SaveAsync(){
    using(db){
        db.add(serializer.deserialize(await RequestAsync());
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
 }
```

The `deserialize` method returns an object and it does not have a specific return type. Assuming the JSON example I provided, if the `Id` property of the `Items` object does not exist in the database, EF proceeds with adding it but if it exists, it throws a duplicate key exception.

I cannot make any query to track duplicates at that level, and I want to configure the Entity Framework (and not in the SQL Server) to ignore duplicates.

Is this supported by EF Core?